# Unity - How to run a timer in parallel to a series of coroutines and WaitForSeconds

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the code below, I have a cycle for enemies appearing and disappearing.

```
IEnumerator EnemyCycle()    {
while (isRepeating)
{

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

canStartUpdatingReset = true;
Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 0f, fTime, currentEnemy.gameObject, false));

coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);

if (currentEnemy.hasWeapon) {
            weaponCycleCoroutines.Add(StartCoroutine(FadeToForWeapon(currentEnemy.weapon.GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 0f, fadeTime, currentEnemy.weapon, false)));

        }
}

yield return new WaitForSeconds (hideTime);

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 1f, fTime, currentEnemy.gameObject, true));

 coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);
 if (currentEnemy.hasWeapon) {
weaponCycleCoroutines.Add(StartCoroutine(FadeToForWeapon(currentEnemy.weapon.GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 1f, fadeTime, currentEnemy.weapon, true)));
}
yield return new WaitForSeconds (showTime);

        }
    }
}
```

I have an `enemyCycleDuration` `float` which is

```
enemyCycleDuration = 60*(hideTime + fadeTime + showTime + fadeTime)
```

Note that `fadeTime` comes from `FadeToForWeapon` and `FadeToForEnemy`. The idea here is I want the `enemyCycleDuration` to be run in parallel to `EnemyCycle()` so it is reset (please see code below) at the same time that

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (showTime);
```

is reached in the  `EnemyCycle()` (end of method).

I am resetting `enemyCycleDuration` in the following way in the update method but `EnemyCycle()` seems to be ahead of `enemyCycleDuration`, always completing before `enemyCycleDuration` is reset. How can I get both to run parallel to each other in timing and complete at the same time?

```
if (canStartUpdatingReset)  {
timeElapsed +=1;
if(timeElapsed >= enemyCycleDuration) {

timeElapsed = 0;

Debug.Log ("Reset CycleDuration");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to something similar to what you ask for I don't use coroutines. I use instead something like this:

```
int TimeBetweenAction1 = 3f;
int TimeBetweenAction2 = 3f;

void Update () {   
    if(Time.time > NextAction1){
        DoAction1();
    }

    if(Time.time > NextAction2){
        DoAction2();
    }

}

void DoAction1(){
    NextAction1 = Time.time + TimeBetweenActions1;
}

void DoAction2(){
    NextAction2 = Time.time + TimeBetweenActions2;
}
```

The action could be from respawn a type of enemies or shoot a gun. You can have as many as you need in a gameObject to manage all enemies respawn, or in different gameObjects linked to different triggers in a Scene...

I know you asked exactly about coroutines, but that may be an easier approach that will do the trick. Let me know if it is useful for your issue or if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: I am open to another approach as long as it is more effective. There are several timers (`hideTime`, `fadeTime` and  `showTime`) within my code. That's why I used a coroutine. Having the same effect without using coroutines is definitely possible, but it seems rather complex to me. I would really appreciate if you could explain further with an example how I can achieve this.